# What should I do being unable to pray at school?

Tags: salat, practical-islam, school

In school I can't pray dhuhr and sometimes asr prayer also because I stay back late so what should I do?

I'm afraid it's not acceptable to pray these prayers late all the time.

My school is run by a Christian lady and all teachers are either Christian, Hindu, etc., but most of the students are Muslim. Mind you I live in a Muslim country, UAE.

Sometimes I get off school at 2:30 which leaves me just enough time for asr.  But sometimes I come home at 6:00 due to my extra subjects.

Answer (score 3):

Assalamu alaikum wa rahmatullahi wa barakatuhu, dear brother!

1. I'm really glad to hear that you turned to the deen.
2. It is very important that you are not just skipping this problem but you are thinking how to solve it. May Allah grant you ease and the best solution and grant all muslims the best solutions also.
3. I will start with next hadith. Sa’d bin Abu Waqqas, said:“*I said: ‘O Messenger of Allah, which people are most severely tested?’ He said: ‘The Prophets, then the next best and the next best. A person is tested according to his religious commitment. If he is steadfast in his religious commitment, he will be tested more severely, and if he is frail in his religious commitment, his test will be according to his commitment. Trials will continue to afflict a person until they leave him walking on the earth with no sin on him.’*” (Sunan Ibn Majah 4023)
4. So be happy with difficulties that Allah puts in your life (and don't forget to smile).
5. I'm a muslim from Russia. When I was at school I faced the same problem, but conditions were really worse. My elder brother and me were the only practicing muslims in school. All teachers were non-muslims (christians or atheists).
6. In fact we solved this problem with the help of Allah as follows. We just went to one teacher with whom we had good relations and asked her to give us some space in her classroom. She understood us and gave us this space for prayers.
7. In university my friend and I are praying just in special places where nobody can see us. Once I was praying in front of people, but only one old lady was really unsatisfied. Others were just watching.
8. So in my opinion try to estimate situation firstly. If your classmates are muslims don't worry and pray in front of them, probably it will be good dawah for them. If you are not sure try to ask some teacher for special place in classroom. I'm not thinking that it will be hard in UAE.
9. Finally, ask Allah and He will help you. Ask Him for persistence, sabr and everything. Don't fear people, fear Allah. May Allah will help you. Ameen.

Wa alaikum assalam wa rahmatullahi wa barakatuhu!

Comment: I thank you for your answer but let me make a slight change I'm a sister in islam . But your answer is really helpful and I will try to talk to my fellow classmates too

Answer (score 1):

Salaam,

Praying is the first pillar of Islam and because of this there are some relaxation in it. 
Islam does not force anyone but teach them in very nice manner to do the Islamic things.
In different Islamic sects the time is different but that difference is must like 10 to 15 minutes except Jumma pray which is almost 30 min.

I have given full details for praying, when it's time start and when it's time end. You can adjust your praying time in the light of below details and it will still be considered "right" and performed.

Praying 5 times in a day: There are 5 times in day when you have to pray to Allah and this is mandatory.

1. Fajar, 2 rakat
2. Zuhar (Duhar), 4 rakat
3. Asar, 4 rakat
4. Magrib, 3 rakat
5. Isha'a), 4 rakat

These does not include any nafal, sunnat etc.

## ==============

## Sunni Sect

## ==============

Fajar:

> Fajr daily prayer must be offered (with loud recitation of the quran) 
>   is from the beginning of dawn to sunrise.

Zuhar:

> **Time begins:** when Sun has exactly halfway between sunrise and sunset
>   (This is when the sun is at the highest point in the sky)
>
> **Time ends:** At the time when the Asr prayer begins (afternoon prayer)
>   Maliki school: if someone prays zuhr 30 minutes before sunset, he is
>   considered to have prayed the prayer "on time".

Asar:

> **Time begins:** The Maliki, Shafi`i, and Hanbali schools say it is at
>   the time when the length of any object's shadow equals the length of 
>   the object itself plus the length of that object's shadow at noon.
>   Hanafi school: it begins when the length of any object's
>   shadow is twice the length of the object plus the length of that
>   object's shadow at noon
>
> **Time ends:** Once the sun has completely set below the horizon. However,
>   it is frowned upon (and sinful in the Maliki school) to delay the
>   prayer without a legitimate excuse to the point of the day in which
>   the sun turns a pale red or orange color as it begins to set, though
>   it would still be considered to have been prayed on time.

Maghrib:

> **Time begins:** When the sun has completely set beneath the horizon;
>   immediately after the Asr prayer period ends.
>
> **Time Ends:** Maliki and Shafi'i schools of law, the prescribed prayer time ends as soon as
>   enough time for a person to purify him/herself and pray has passed.
>   After that, according to the Maliki school, the Period of Necessity
>   lasts until a little before dawn, i.e., the beginning of Fajr prayer.
>   Most other scholarly opinions hold that the time for Maghrib prayer
>   ends when the time for Isha'a salat begins.

Isha'a:

> **Time begins:** According to the Hanafi school, Isha begins when 
>   complete darkness has arrived and the white twilight in the sky has
>   disappeared. 
>   Maliki and Shafi'i schools, the time begins when the red thread has
>   disappeared from the sky.
>
> **Time ends:** At the beginning of dawn when the time for Fajr prayer 
>   begins. However, it is frowned upon to delay the prayer without a
>   legitimate excuse past the first 1/3 of the night ("night" in Islamic
>   law means the time between the entrance of the Maghrib prayer and the
>   entrance of the Fajr prayer). According to an opinion in the Maliki
>   school, the prohibition is from delaying the prayer beyond 1/2 the
>   night, rather than just 1/3.

## ==============

## Shia Sect

## ==============

Fajar:

> **Start** Fajr daily prayer starting time is beginning of dawn till you see the
>   whitnes of morning (which is called Saher). 
>   **End** Once Sun rays are visible you cannot pray it and after that you have to pray it as Qaza.

Zuhar (Duhar):

> **Start** When Sun has exactly halfway between sunrise and sunset
>   (This is when the sun is at the highest point in the sky)
>   **End** When Sun is down, not fully but the redness is visible in sky (i don't know what
>   its name in English)  After that you have to pray it as Qaza.

Asar:

> **Start** You can pray it right after reciting Zuhar 
>   **End** When Sun is down, not fully but the redness is visible in sky. After that you have to pray it as
>   Qaza.

Maghrib:

> **Start** You can pray it once Sun is fully down and the redness in sky is no
>   more visible 
>   **End** You can still pray till mid night.

Isha'a:

> **Start** You can pray it right after you recite Maghrib 
>   **End** You can still pray till mid night.

In Shia sect Zuhr can be followed by Asr once the midday prayer has been recited and sufficient time has passed, and Maghrib can be followed by Isha'a once the evening prayer has been recited and sufficient time has passed.

***Despite the relatively long period in which valid prayers can be recited, it is considered important to recite the prayer as soon as the time begins. But if you have difficulties to offer pray then you can delay it until you can offer it.***